# How to align to the right side a widget Tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter, frontend

I want to create a resizable window, and I want all the widgets in there to resize when I resize the window.
For this, I'm trying to use `grid()` and give relative positions to the widgets.
This is the code:

```
c = tk.Canvas(width=400, height=320)
c.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='w')
Label(root, textvariable=balance_string_var).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="we")

balance_string_var.set("LABEL")

listbox = Listbox(root, height=30, width=100)
listbox.grid(column=1, row=0, rowspan=2, sticky="e")
```

I want the Listbox to be aligned to the right (look image).
[image: on]
How can I do it? Thanks

Comment: Read up on [`grid_columnconfigure(index, **options) `](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm#Tkinter.Grid.grid_columnconfigure-method)

Comment: And what options should I use? I don't want to use the padding

Comment: I tried without success..

Comment: Add `root.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)`.

Comment: This did the trick! Could you explain this to me, please?

Comment: If you write down an answer, I will choose as the best one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [document](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm#Tkinter.Grid.grid_columnconfigure-method) for the `weight` option of `columnconfigure()`:

> *weight=*
>
> A relative weight used to distribute additional space between columns.
>   A column with the weight 2 will grow twice as fast as a column with weight 1.
>   The default is 0, which means that the column will not grow at all.

The `listbox` widget is put in column 1 of the grid layout of `root` and column 1 is the last column that contains widget, so calling `root.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)` will make column 1 to use all the remaining horizontal space.

And so setting `sticky='e'` in `listbox.grid(..., sticky='e')` will then put the `listbox` at the right-most of `root` window.

Answer (score 1):

Use place instead, .place(relx=0, rely=0.05, relheight=0.03, relwidth=1) !! using 0-1.0 instead of pixels totally scales them properly, it's more flexible than grid

or use pack(side="right")

Comment: Ok thanks, but there is no way doing this with grid?